# How to show webview in Viewpager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have an issue while showing webview in viewpager. I did used the AwesomeViewPager example and added webview but it's not rendering, if anyone has any example.

Your help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add some parameters to it

```
    info_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    info_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    info_view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    // info_view.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    // info_view.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    info_view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    info_view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    info_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    info_view.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, but still its not working, i am using simple url info_view.loadUrl("http://news.google.co.in/"); but webview shows web page not available.

Comment: Url did contain http but somehow its not showing in my first comment.

Comment: If you could send me an example